# vscodeの括弧の補完で改行をしないようにしたい

Tags: c++, vscode

私は現在vscodeでC++を利用しています.
今の状態としては以下です
OS:ubuntu 18.04LTS
vscode:1.44.2
C++:g++ 7.5.0
です.
vscodeのextentionで
C/C++,
C++ Intellisense
ともに最新版をインストールしています.

この状態で補完をすると

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    /* code */
}
```

のようになっています.
この補完を

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {　// このように{の前で改行をしてほしくない
    /* code */
}
```

のように設定したいのですが,可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

### 解決方法

ワークスペースのルートディレクトリに `.clang-format` という名前のファイルを作り、ClangFormat の設定を行ってください。設定例をふたつ置いておきます：

例1：`BasedOnStyle` を設定する。たとえば下は LLVM coding standards 準拠にする例です。

```yaml
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
```

例2：`BreakBeforeBraces` や `BraceWrapping` の設定を個別に行う。下はひとつの例です。

```yaml
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
```

### 解説

C/C++ 拡張機能のデフォルト設定のコード整形では、ワークスペースにある `.clang-format` というファイルがあればこの内容に従い、無ければ VS Code の `C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle` に従います。参考：https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_code-formatting

`.clang-format` というのは [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) のための設定ファイルです。リンクしたドキュメントのように各種設定が行えます。